# MongoDB $pull value from array of ObjectIDs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this document in my collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52718433e18a711923000005"),
    "owners" : [
        ObjectId("52718433e18a711923000004"),
        ObjectId("52ed40dccc5bc50000000003"),
        ObjectId("52ed4171abe2780000000003")
    ]
}
```

I have the following statement, where I am trying to remove one of the values in `owners` field:

```
Business.update({_id:req.body._id}, {$pull:{"owners":req.body.userid}}, function(err){
    if(err){
        res.json(500, {message:"Could not remove user from admin list"});
    }else{
        res.json(200);
    }
});
```

I know that `req.body._id` and `req.body.userid` have valid values:

```
{ _id: '52718433e18a711923000005',
  userid: '52ed4171abe2780000000003' }
```

Other operations, such as finding business by ID, etc, work, so it's not an ObjectId format issue. What else could it be?

-- 
Edit: here is my (abbreviated) schema definition:

```
var BusinessSchema = new Schema({
    business_name: {type: String, required: true},
    owners: {type: Array}
});
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include your schema definition?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current schema doesn't provide any direction to Mongoose regarding the data type contained within the `owners` array field.  If you want Mongoose to cast your string to an ObjectID you need to provide type information in your schema:

```js
var BusinessSchema = new Schema({
    business_name: {type: String, required: true},
    owners: [{type: Schema.ObjectId}]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a conversion to ObjectId is required when trying to match values to pull. But not to search. So this works:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

Business.update({_id:req.body._id}, {$pull:{"owners": new ObjectId(req.body.userid)}}, function(err){
    if(err){
        res.json(500, {message:"Could not remove user from admin list"});
    }else{
        res.json(200);
    }
});
```

-- 
Edit: So, if I change my schema from `owners: {type: Array}` to `owners: [Schema.Types.ObjectId]`, I can skip the conversion, and my original statement works.

Comment: The casting of the `String` to a `ObjectId` is required to me with `[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'owner' }]`. Was there a change in MongoDB / Mongoose since '14? Could it also be that `ref`is interfering with the cast?